# How to use Wordpress wp_remote_post if I don't need to get a response?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Using `wp_remote_post` to send form data (`Contact Form 7`) to external API (CRM). API is heavy (checking emails, confirmation letters, etc), so I don't want PHP to block any processes, while waiting for a response (I don't need response at all, just send).

Still, even with `'blocking' => false` it does — if I activate confirmation emails on external API, Wordpress users need to wait several seconds before form is processed.

What am I doing wrong? :) Code:

```
// POST-request to API
wp_remote_post('http://crm.site.com/get_record', array(
    'timeout' => 5,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => false,
    'headers' => array() ,
    'body' => $send_data,
    'cookies' => array()
));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think method is missing here, add method and try

```
   $response = wp_remote_post('http://crm.site.com/get_record', array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => false,
    'headers' => array() ,
    'body' => $send_data,
    'cookies' => array()
   ));
```

And check response:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome! this fixed the issue

Comment: Why do you need to specify the method when the method itself is making post request, I mean the default is POST already, isn't that redundant?

Comment: Yes, POST is optional you can ignore that as well. @svelandiag

Comment: but I mean, why did it solve the issue? Im confused

Comment: @svelandiag It didn't, something else must have, perhaps reading the error message properly. The request is exactly the same because that is just a helper function which adds only `'method' => 'POST'` to a standard request.