# WordPress - How to make API call to external server

Tags: .net, wordpress, api

Hoping no one has asked this before. I'm new to WordPress but I've been in IT for years. I mostly work in .Net framework but trying out WordPress. Anyway, I have an API server built already. I need to make calls to my API server from my WordPress site. How do I do a simple post from WordPress site to my API server. I don't want to expose my API credentials etc so I'd like the button click to perform the logic in the backend if possible. Videos or tuts would be great if anyone has information.

Comment: I'm sure a little Google search will help you. Here's one result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041684/how-to-use-wordpress-wp-remote-post-if-i-dont-need-to-get-a-response/52041879

Comment: This for using Word Press API. I want to send data from Word Press to an external API and receive data from my external API.